# Spring, when I run my project, it is redirected to a login page

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I was having trouble connecting to the mysql database. I tested several things and decide to ask for help here. A guy helped me.

This is my code in aplciation properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springone?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl= true
spring.jpa.show-sql= true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

He said for me to add add this "? ServerTimezone = UTC" to the url. The project stopped giving error and executed, but now a login page appears and in my project there is no login page. The only thing it has is an index page

Someone knows what it is? Please

Comment: Show us your pom.xml. If you have spring security dependency it protects everything by default and asks you to login. I think that's what's going on. You should white list the index page to always allow

Comment: See this on how to configure the security. https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-boot-blog-app/blob/master/src/main/java/gt/app/config/security/SecurityConfig.java#L30

Comment: Also, if you don't want the security.. and believe that the security dependency is there unnecessarily, you can remove those dependencies to not get the login page.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks